# Why 'pale' yellow instead of 'light' yellow and what are the other colors used with 'pale'?

Tags: british-english, collocations

In LDOCE, *'light'* is considered a synonym of *'pale'* which means having more white in it than usual, and I also thought pale and light are interchangeable when it came to colors.

I'm reading 'English Vocabulary in Use', intermediate level by Cambridge University Press which is based on British English, in which there is a note that says,

> **Note**: With some colours, we use pale, not light, e.g. pale yellow.

Firstly, Is it something exclusive to British English?

And secondly, what are the other colours that you refer to as *'pale'* and not *'light'*.

I took a [picture](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=9111859148) of the page in the book. Just click on the picture. You can find the Note on the left.

Comment: I found this on Google, [Pale Brown VS Light Brown](http://colors.findthedata.com/compare/618-622/Light-Brown-vs-Pale-Brown)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technically "pale" refers to the saturation of the color, and "light/dark" refers to [luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance), or the perceived brightness.

In AmE usage however, light can also mean a color that is not intense. I can't think of an instance where pale could be used for a color that is intense but light (or bright).

As I mentioned in my comment, in general conversation, you can use pale or light interchangeably when referring to a color and be understood. If the register is more formal and you're writing for a UK English audience, you should follow the advice in your book just to be certain your phrasing won't seem odd.

For each of the examples below, I went to DuckDuckGo.com and searched for images that matched the term. I had success with each color except for pale dark green - I ended up searching for "pale dark green" fabric to find an image where the color filled the frame. I picked from the first few results the ones I felt were distinct enough to show the difference. There is not a definite line where we can say "this green is pale to everyone who looks at it". Click on the image to see the original sized image.

This is both a light green and a pale green:

[image]

This is a light green but not a pale green:
[image]

This is bright green (both light in luminance and intense in color):
[image]

This is a pale dark green (might also be called gray-green):
[image]

This is a dark green (not pale This color is often called emerald or emerald green):
[image]

Comment: @Colleen V: So we can use light with yellow or pink. Should I ignore the note in the book? You disagree with the notion it has put, right?

Comment: @Azad I think like everything in English, it depends on the context. If you're speaking informally, I think you would be understood if you said "pale yellow" or "light yellow" and you wouldn't sound odd (at least in the US). If you are writing formally for a British audience, I would follow the book's advice.

Comment: I see, so it's mainly the matter of register and locality. Thanks 

Comment: I emphatically agree that "pale" is a term of saturation and "light" is a term of luminance.  As demonstrated in this brilliant answer, a color can be light and pale or light and not pale.  I would argue further a color can be dark, yet pale, such as a desaturated brown.

Comment: I agree with all of these except "pale dark," which sounds weird to me.

Comment: What about dark pale green? Does the word order make a difference? It sounded a bit odd to me too but there's nothing wrong with a pale dark something as far as I can tell.  @sumelic

Comment: The word order doesn't make a difference. It's the meaning that doesn't fit. For me, something that is "pale" has to also be "light." This could be relative to something else, but it excludes the concept of "dark."

Comment: @sumelic I can understand that - what would you call the pale dark green color?

Comment: I think maybe gray-green or grayish green, as you've said. Or maybe "muddy green."

Comment: I think this is related to [Why are there no dark yellows, or bright violets?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/10412/1943), on Photography Stack Exchange. In a very real sense, _all_ yellow is light, so saying "light yellow" can feel a bit redundant.

Comment: Speaking _technically_, those colours are not the best examples. #1 and #5 are called Pale but their saturations = 230 & 234, both high numbers. #2 called Not-pale has sat. = 171, moderate. This is a direct contradiction of the opening statement. Human vision says "#1 & #5 are not vivid" and "#2 is vivid" disagreeing with technical descriptons of saturation because technically saturation is measured at constant lightness but those range from lightness 30 to 201. In this case, invoking a technical specification is extremely unhelpful as it contradicts common understanding of the words.

Comment: @Smartybartfast I'm not understanding. I wasn't trying to give a technical definition, but rather explain common usage (I just mentioned it because common usage tends to diverge from the technical definition). I searched for images that people had described by the terms I labelled them with - those colors don't represent technical "truth" but rather the most relevant hits with that description from a search engine. 'Vivid' is a whole different question :P

Comment: The answer starts 'Technically "pale" refers to the saturation...' which invites commentary on how the technical and common understandings differ. The question is about colour saturation so we will disagree on vivid as being a "whole different question" as in my part of the world (see how I spell "colour" unlike you poor colonials who can't afford the extra "u"  :) ) vivid = "very high _saturation_ or purity; produced by a _pure or almost pure colouring_ agent" (thanks dictionary.com)

Answer (score 4):

According to [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pale%20yellow%2Clight%20yellow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpale%20yellow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20yellow%3B%2Cc0), **pale** rather than **light** is the preferred term for most of the colours that I tried. The difference is much greater for yellow than other colours, and for BrE than AmE.  Cream and pink are very much more common than pale yellow and pale red, though cream may include the dairy product as well.

The only colours I have found where light was the preferred term were brown (AmE and BrE) and grey/gray (AmE only).

For yellow, which is perceived as a bright colour, **pale** is the preferred term, and for brown, which is perceived as a dark colour, **light** is the preferred term.

Comment: Pale in AmE is more "literary" and light is more colloquial (unless you're speaking with a designer). Did you limit the search to the British corpra?

Comment: An NGram comparing pale/light yellow as a noun in the US and GB corpora between 1900 and 2000 shows that pale occurs more often in both, but a much more often in GB than US (determined by a quick and dirty subtraction) `pale yellow_NOUN:eng_us_2012,pale yellow_NOUN:eng_gb_2012,light yellow_NOUN:eng_us_2012,light yellow_NOUN:eng_gb_2012` Substituting other colors for yellow is interesting. Try pale blue versus light blue `blue_NOUN:eng_us_2012,pale blue_NOUN:eng_gb_2012,light blue_NOUN:eng_us_2012,light blue_NOUN:eng_gb_2012`

Comment: @colleenV: interesting. Do Americans spell yellow differently, or something? I didn't know that you could specify parts of speech and corpora in a search: thanks for that!

Comment: I'm a little on the fence about specify the color as a noun though. I think you can do `pale yellow _NOUN_` as well. That might tell us if there is an adjective/noun difference.

Comment: Also, technically, there is no such thing as a pale white, grey, or black because they have no hue. I have seen "pale white" but I think it is actually a different sense of pale than "pale yellow". I'd have to think about it some more.

Comment: @ColleenV: relative usage between noun and adjective seems consistent. TBH, I only really considered looking at adjectives. Technically, yes... but technical usage tends to be much more precise than laymen's usage. Not necessarily because laymen don't understand the finer points of the meanings- often technical people hijack existing words and add their own precise meaning. FYI, pale gray/grey > pale white >> pale black.

Comment: I agree - technical usage isn't "more correct". It's more important to be precise in some situations than in others. 'I saw a rider on a pale horse' potentially conveys so much more meaning than saying 'I saw man riding a white horse.', but the more precise version would be better if you were explaining what happened to the police.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely certain this applies to all the scenarios, but to what it's worth, Pale doesn't necessarily mean addition of white element pigments to the colors. Pale means:

> Lacking color or intensity.

You might want to visit [this link](http://wikidiff.com/light/pale) to see the difference between the two words.

Also, even though they are synonymous, there are many places where you cannot use them interchangeability. For example,

> Look at her pale skin.

You don't say *"light skin"*.

Additionally, consider the following sentence:

> "Are you okay? You look awfully *pale*."

This *'pale'* refers to the commonly used idiom "turning white in fear".

Comment: Yes, Varun KN thanks for your comment. Though I just don't understand why 'pale' can be used with some colors instead of 'light'. It seems it has something to do with collocation that I can't find a list for.

Comment: Actually let me edit the title to make my point clearer. Sorry for being ambiguous in first place.

Comment: You may say "light skin" as well as pale skin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_skin

Comment: but 'light skin' is kind of permanent feature, while 'you look pale' is more like temporary effect of you being exhausted or sth.

Comment: @Yabko I'm not sure about BrE, but in AmE "pale skin" can be a permanent feature, but it describes almost white/colorless skin, or skin that lacks [melanin](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/melanin). Light skin seems to be relative to dark skin and could refer to skin that has some color, so it would depend on the context how close to pale skin it is.