# Bright yellow or light yellow?

Tags: word-difference

What's the correct term about the colour of lemon juice. Is it [bright](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bright?q=BRIGHT) or [light](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/light?q=LIGHT)? I am confused between these two terms. When we see any color we can classify it  into two main groups: dark or bright /light. Based on Cambridge dictionary the meaning of **bright** is strong in colour. Does it mean that we can use dark and bright color as synonyms?

Comment: Related question: [Why 'pale' yellow instead of 'light' yellow and what are the other colors used with 'pale'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/85444/9161)

Answer (score 19):

There is some overlap and some contrast in the meanings. It matters whether you are talking about paint or light.

If you take a pure yellow colour, such as the yellow colour in the rainbow, or the yellow of the skin of a lemon, this is a *bright* yellow.  Painters use "cadmium yellow paint" for this.

If you take some cadmium yellow paint and mix some white the colour becomes paler, more like the colour of cream. This is a *light* yellow.

If you take the same yellow paint and add a little black you will get a *dark* yellow (which quickly becomes brown as you add more black, so "dark yellow" is not actually used very often)

If you have a yellow lamp, there is an ambiguity in the meaning of "bright" as it could refer to the purity of the yellow, or the power of the lamp. A powerful lamp is bright and a weak one is dim. This meaning of "bright" is different from the meaning applied to paint.

Examples:

> Van Gogh used bright yellow paint for his sunflowers paintings.
>
> I used a pale yellow to paint the walls of my bedroom, because the bright yellow was overpowering.
>
> If your urine is a dark yellow, you may be suffering from dehydration. Drink plenty of water!

Comment: *Contrast* - I see what you did there ;) "[Contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision)) is determined by the **difference in the color** ***and*** **brightness** of the object and other objects *within the same field of view*." Therefore this question is unanswerable because there is neither a picture of lemon juice, nor of anything to *contrast* it against. Also, I believe the OP is actually talking about [luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance), which is rated in [candela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela_per_square_metre).

Answer (score 17):

**Light** means a color that tends toward white. **Dark** means a color that tends toward black. **Bright** means intense in color but not a dark color.

As applied to yellow, in the squares below, the middle center one is bright yellow, the bottom center one is light yellow, and the top left one is dark yellow. Judgment can vary about how to name shades in between.
 [image]

Comment: In other words: ‘bright’ refers to _saturation_ as well as to luminance.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between lightness and brightness, with respect to color, is a difference in color space used to describe the object. Subjectively some people interchange the usage, and of course conversion from one color space to another is usually possible; that's not always lossless.

HSL (hue, saturation and lightness) is often called the "bi-hexcone model" while HSV (hue, saturation and brightness or value) is often called the "hexcone model".

Wikipedia's webpage [HSL and HSB/HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) explains:

> - The HSB/HSV representation models **the way paints** of different colors **mix** together, with the saturation dimension resembling various shades of brightly colored paint, and the value dimension resembling the mixture of those paints with varying amounts of black or white paint.
> - The HSL model attempts to resemble more **perceptual** color **models** such as the Natural Color System (NCS) or Munsell color system, placing fully saturated colors around a circle at a lightness value of ​1⁄2, where a lightness value of 0 or 1 is fully black or white, respectively.
>
> ...
>
> **Brightness** and colorfulness are **absolute measures**, which usually **describe the spectral distribution** of light entering the eye, while **lightness** and chroma are **measured relative to** some **white point**, and are thus often used for descriptions of surface colors, remaining roughly constant even as brightness and colorfulness change with different illumination. Saturation can be defined as either the ratio of colorfulness to brightness or that of chroma to lightness.

[image: HSL vs. HSB]

A simplified and not completely accurate description is to say that lighter objects are whiter while brighter objects are more colorful. In the HSL colorspace an object that is 50% light is equal to an object in the HSB colorspace that is 100% bright. The *inaccuracy* in such an exact conversion comes from the [brain's perception of color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#Color_in_the_human_brain).

Referring to lemonade as bright or light yellow is unlikely to spark an argument. Lightness is the perceived reflectance of white. Brightness is how much of the color (not black, grey, or white) is reflected towards your eye (the color intensity, not the white intensity).

Perhaps the easiest way to remember the difference is: [Lightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightness) is perceived illumination (assuming white light) while brightness is the [luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance), the amount of color (how *far* from black, with equal amounts of color, furthest away, being white).

Answer (score 0):

NO, dark and bright are not same. Dark colour means- deep colour. dark colours are usually a little faint and bright colour means- bright colours usually glow and are eye catching. so, basically bright colours are a little glowy and dark colours are a little faint and deep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain it in layman's terms:

The opposite meaning of bright is dark. The sun is bright. A highlighter is bright. The night is dark. It's about how dazzling a color is.

The opposite meaning of light is dull. Think of pastel colors and muted colors. It's about how much white/gray/black there is in a color.